# Mention the first immediate action in an '-ing' clause in front of the main clause

Tags: continuous-aspect, absolute-constructions

Page 585 of the Collins English Usage reads

> To indicate that someone did one thing immediately after
> another, you can mention the first thing they did in an '-ing' clause
> in front of the main clause.
>
> ***Leaping out of bed**, he dressed so quickly that he put his boots on the
> wrong feet.*

However, I find the semantics of the example jarring, because *leap* is an action that takes just a moment, unlike for example *He used to shave, comb and get dressed while cooking breakfast*.

Comment: 'Dress' is seen here as a punctive verb. Nothing is precisely punctive, and 'punctiveness' is relative. _Leaping out of bed, he dressed at once._ //  ?? _Leaping out of bed, he spent two hours trying to find his gold cufflinks._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what I find jarring is _leaping_, unlike _**having leaped** out of bed,..._

Comment: But as Collins says, a PP clause is often used in that way. _Seeing an iceberg through the fog, the captain ordered hard aport._ // _Turning right, he soon found himself in a part of town he didn't know.' // _Removing his jacket, Sally jumped into the lake andhelped the boy swim ashore_. //// Of course, simultaneity is also possible: Waiting in the street, he suddenly saw the Archbishop of York's car appear._  //// One assumes 'after' and 'while' are deletions in the two types mentioned.